# Kendo button navigation in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, button, kendo-ui

Am using Kendo button in MVC4 application .How and where should i write the Navigation to another page on button click .

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
.Name("btncancel")
.HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
.Content("Cancel"))
```

I did like this but i am not getting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btncancel').click(function (e)
  {
      location.href = '@Url.Content("~//Company/Index.cshtml")';
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Company")';
```

Comment: im glad it worked for you.  would you mind marking my answer as the correct answer?